# php function not return result from sql when I user sql with 'NOT IN' to query

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I use sql command to select data from oracle server and got result like this

```
select *
  from login_log
  where userid not in (select userid
                         from last_log
                         where userid is not null) and
        LOGIN_ID='423'
```

but when I use this sql in php function it's not return anything

```
$strSQL = "select * from login_log where userid not in (select userid from last_log where userid is not null) and  LOGIN_ID='423'";
$objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);
oci_bind_by_name($objParse, ':sftp_id', $sftp_id);
oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
$nrows = oci_fetch_all($objParse, $results, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```

I don't know why I didn't get result with "NOT IN" 
I try to test the code by change "NOT IN" to "IN" like this

```
$strSQL = "select * from login_log where userid in (select userid from last_log where userid is not null) and  LOGIN_ID='423'";
```

And it's return result normally, I don't know what happen with. Can any body 
help me please.

Comment: I am guessing that `last_log` doesn't have a column called `userid`.

Comment: last_log have column name userid already, and I test sql command by execute in SQLDeveloper and got return correctly

Comment: Why are you binding a value to parameter `:sftp_id` which doesn't exist in your query?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is because the id `423` is in and when your query ask for not in, it doesn't return anything, as the code is current and correct.

Comment: Oh sorry I copy wrong code the actually the sql code is
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN_LOG WHERE USERID NOT IN (SELECT USERID FROM LAST_LOG) and SFTP_ID = :sftp_id";

Comment: I agree with Jonathan Gagne. Your current code seems correct and if it returns something when you ask for "IN" but nothing for "NOT IN", it must be that all "USERID" with the right "sftp_id" ARE inside the "LAST_LOG" table.

Comment: I test test the sql code by execute in SQLDeveloper and "NOT IN" return result correctly but when use in php not return anything, so make me confuse